# Question on type casting with Dart's map()

Tags: dart

I think I must be missing something on the way Dart performs runtime type checks. Can someone explain to me how the third use of `map()` below is wrong?

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

class Foo {
  final int bar;
  Foo.fromJson(data) : bar = data['bar'];
}

void main() {
  final data = json.decode('[{"bar": 42}]');
  
  List<Foo> getFoosCast() => data.map<Foo>(Foo.fromJson).toList();
  print(getFoosCast()); // [Instance of 'Foo']

  // return type is inferred as 'dynamic' despite the cast on map<>?
  getFoosUntyped() => data.map<Foo>(Foo.fromJson).toList();
  print(getFoosUntyped()); // [Instance of 'Foo']

  List<Foo> getFoos() => data.map(Foo.fromJson).toList();
  print(getFoos()); // Unhandled exception: type 'List<dynamic>'' is not a subtype of 'List<Foo>'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issues start with this line:

```dart
final data = json.decode('[{"bar": 42}]');
```

Problem being that `json.decode` is defined to return `dynamic` and `data` will therefore be statically assigned the type `dynamic` which basically means Dart gives up trying to help you with types.

That means the rest of your program gets typed `dynamic` since any call on a `dynamic` type, will also result in a `dynamic` typed result.

The reason for `json.decode` returns `dynamic` is because the returned type fully depend on what JSON string you are parsing. In your case, you are parsing a `List` so the returned type will be `List<dynamic>`, but for other JSON strings, we could end up returning the following types: `List<String, dynamic>`, `String`, `double`, `int`.

We therefore need to help Dart a bit here and do a type-cast so we prevent the `dynamic` from happening. So in your case we would do:

```dart
final data = json.decode('[{"bar": 42}]') as List<dynamic>;
```

This makes `data` variable to be the type `List<dynamic>`. Which also means that your later call to `map()` is the `map()` function from `List` and does now know how it works with generics.

Note, we can't type-cast `data` to be `List<Map<String, int>>` since the returned list from `json.decode` will always be `List<dynamic>` regardless of what kind of JSON list we have. Same for maps which will also always be `Map<String, dynamic>`.

This is one reason why we want to convert these JSON objects into objects of our own data classes like you are trying to do in your example.

Comment: OK thanks a lot.

I think I'm misunderstanding exactly what Dart's `as` does, because I thought it was equivalent to TypeScript's, or C++'s `reinterpret_cast` and just forced the compiler to re-type the value, but clearly it's not the case.

Typically, I'm not quite getting why casting `data` to `List<Map<String, int>>` isn't possible - I'd expect `as` to let me cast `dynamic` to pretty much anything.

Comment: @MatthieuDazy Yeah, the `as` works a bit different since all objects in Dart knows their full type including any generics on the type. So when doing type-casting, Dart will check at runtime if this type-cast can actually be done when you do it. This will prevent you from hitting into issues later on when you e.g. try call a method on the object and you first here learn the truth about what the object can do. So therefore, we can't just type-cast a `List<dynamic>` into `List<String>` since the list object itself have the type `List<dynamic>` and we can't change that fact (without a new list).